# How to delete entity which associated with java map list

Tags: java, hibernate, entity

I have an entity which has map list with sub enitities. When I want to delete this entity , I've got

> Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (kobalt.category_categoryitem,

error and I use hibernate. Is there anyone who can solve this problem ?

```
@Entity
public class Product implements BaseEntity {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private int kobilId;
    private String code;
    @Column(unique = true)
    private long barcode;
    private String productName;
    @Column
    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @Fetch(value = FetchMode.SUBSELECT)
    @Cascade(org.hibernate.annotations.CascadeType.DELETE)
    private Map<Category, CategoryItem> itemList;
```

Comment: Looks like your code not referenced the error. Because there is no attribute category_categoryitem

Answer (score 0):

Looks like relationship structure is not correct in your case. When you are trying to delete foreign key corresponding value it can't delete primary key corresponding value. In cascade rule relationship should be like as when you delete primary key corresponding attribute then it should delete all foreign key corresponding attributes. But can't be vice-versa. That is your case i think so try to correct your relationships.                                                 For example consider "employee - address" relationship where employee has array of address. So relationship should be like as when employee is deleted, all the corresponding address should vanish. But on the other hand if relationship is not correct and you try to delete an address then it can't be possible to delete employee, as a result you'll get such exception as in your case.